# How to print integer, instead ascii value?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, fasm

I want to add five numbers in loop and print that sum. This is my code.

```
format MZ
stack sth:256
entry codeseg: main

segment sdat use16
;ds segment x
tabl db 1,2,3,4,10


segment sth use16
db 256 dup (?)

segment codeseg use16

main:
mov ax, sdat
mov ds, ax

;mov ax, sth
;mov ss, ax
;mov sp, 256

xor ax,ax
mov bx,tabl
mov cx,5
add:
        add ax,[bx]
        inc bx
        loop add

mov dx, ax
mov ah, 02h
int 21h


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
ret
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'd like to print out the sum, not the value of the ascii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the content of the AX register into an ASCII string which can be shown by the operating system. I've updated your code accordingly, among other changes. Now your challenge is to figure it all out ;-)

```
format MZ
stack 256
entry codeseg:main

segment dataseg use16
tabl db 1,2,3,4,10
outstr db 8 dup ('$')

segment codeseg use16

main:
mov ax, dataseg
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

xor ax,ax
mov bx,tabl
mov cx,5
addd:
    add al,[bx]
    adc ah, 0
    inc bx
    loop addd

lea di, [outstr]
call ax2dec

lea dx, [outstr]
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

ax2dec:                                 ; Args: AX:number ES:DI: pointer to string
    mov bx, 10                          ; Base 10 -> divisor
    xor cx, cx                          ; CX=0 (number of digits)
  Loop_1:
    xor dx, dx                          ; Clear DX for division
    div bx                              ; AX = DX:AX / BX   Remainder DX
    push dx                             ; Push remainder for LIFO in Loop_2
    inc cx                              ; inc cl = 2 bytes, inc cx = 1 byte
    test ax, ax                         ; AX = 0?
    jnz Loop_1                          ; No: once more
  Loop_2:
    pop ax                              ; Get back pushed digits
    or al, 00110000b                    ; Conversion to ASCII
    stosb                               ; Store only AL to [ES:DI] (DI is a pointer to a string)
    loop Loop_2                         ; Until there are no digits left
    mov BYTE [es:di], '$'               ; Termination character for 'int 21h fn 09h'
    ret
```

Comment: It works great, but I have another question. Is there a possibility to add value from array immediately(in loop), without doing conversion from ascii to integer?

Comment: @Paweł. I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. There is no conversion from ASCII to integer. The assembler has stored `tabl` already as integer. If you don't want to split the addition (ADD & ADC), declare `table`as an array of WORD (`DW` instead of `DB`).. Then you can add the value "instantly" (did you mean that?) with `ADD AX,[BX]`.

Comment: @Pawel: ... and you have to change `inc bx` to `add bx,2` because `[bx]` needs an address (bytewise), not an index..